# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() view returning null

Tags: laravel, variables, foreach, controller, laravel-models

When I created a variable in the Model named "statuses" and called it back in controller I got the array data. However when calling the second variable it's returning null and giving me error in the blade.

In Model

```
/**
 * Statuses.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $statuses = [
    0 => 'InActive',
    1 => 'Published',
    2 => 'Draft',
    3 => 'Scheduled',
];

/**
 * Visibilities.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $visibilities = [
    0 => 'Public',
    1 => 'Private',
    2 => 'Password Protected',
];
```

In the Controller

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    $article        = new Post();
    $categories     = Category::all();
    $tags           = Tag::all();
    $statuses       = $article->statuses;
    $visibilities   = $article->visibilities;

    return view('posts.create', compact('categories','tags','statuses', 'visibilities'));
}
```

When I `dd($article)` I get

[image: dd of article]

When I `dd($statuses)` I get

[image: Statuses]

When I `dd($visibilities)` it returns null while it there

And than I call it in blade

```
                        @foreach($visibilities as $key => $value)
                            <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ (isset($post->visibility) && $post->visibility == $key) ? 'selected' : '' }} >{{$value}}</option>
                        @endforeach
```

I get an error message

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View:

What did I do wrong to get null return for visibilities?

EDIT: I'm pasting my trait for relation

```
namespace App\Models\Traits\Attributes;

trait BlogAttributes
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActionButtonsAttribute()
    {
        return '<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="'.trans('labels.backend.access.users.user_actions').'">'.
                $this->getEditButtonAttribute('edit-blog', 'admin.blogs.edit').
                $this->getDeleteButtonAttribute('delete-blog', 'admin.blogs.destroy').
                '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * Get Display Status Attribute.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public function getDisplayStatusAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->statuses[$this->status] ?? null;
    }

    /**
     * Get Statuses Attribute.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public function getStatusesAttribute(): array
    {
        return $this->statuses;
    }

        /**
     * Get Display Visibility Attribute.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public function getDisplayVisibilityAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->visibilities[$this->visibility] ?? null;
    }

    /**
     * Get Visibility Attribute.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public function getDisplayVisibilitiesAttribute(): array
    {
        return $this->visibilities;
    }
}
```

Comment: when you dd $article->visibilities in the controller what do you get?

Comment: The same result "null"

Comment: not sure maybe the annotation ->visibilities reserved for something try to rename it and see if it is works. For example $avaibleVisibilities

Comment: Exactly I thought of that and I did already but no luck still "null"

Comment: you should be getting `null` for both since they are protected properties (not visible from outside the class) which would cause `__get` to be called which would try to return an attribute/relationship or `null` ... did you create an accessor for the `statuses`?

Comment: If you are mentioning the Trait I've edited the question with the code added

Comment: you have an accessor for the `statuses` attribute which returns that array, that is why you get the array  ... you don't have one for `visibilities`

Comment: But I created an accessor for the visibilities as well public function `getDisplayVisibilitiesAttribute(): array` and `public function getDisplayVisibilityAttribute(): string`

Comment: no, that would be for the attribute `displayVisibility` which is not `visibilities`

Comment: Excuse me can you elaborate more, and do me a favor pasting the solution as an answer. Thank you

Comment: `displayVisibilities != visibilities` ....  `get{AttributeName}Attribute` is the format for accessors ... the only accessors related to 'visibilitiy' you have defined are for the attributes `displayVisibility` and `displayVisibilities`,  so you would have to try accessing the property `displayVisibilities` to use the last one, `$post->displayVisibilities`

Comment: Ok got the idea thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lagbox helped resolving the issue.

It was changing `getDisplayVisibilitiesAttribute()` to `getVisibilitiesAttribute()`